# Should I include commas to offset an if clause?

Tags: sentence-construction, punctuation, if

In cases like this one, should I include commas to offset an *if* clause?

> The article explored the benefits of natural forest regeneration – a cheaper and more viable, if less tangible, alternative to conventional tree planting

Or leave them out?

> The article explored the benefits of natural forest regeneration – a cheaper and more viable if less tangible alternative to conventional tree planting

Comment: In cases like which one - the subject line, or the text that you quoted about the article? I think both of these look better with commas, and the grammarians might tell you that the commas are necessary, but you could probably get away without them.

Comment: It's easier to grasp the sense if you use commas.

Comment: Does the edit imply that you don't "put" punctuation marks? 

Comment: I just edited it to make the question clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding punctuation in most cases makes it easier for the readers to understand it, otherwise it is a matter of self-preference. But it is **preferred** to have them. It improves understanding and readability, due to the punctuation "slowing" the reader down - one of the reasons why we put in a full stop to separate a run on sentence.